# Designing a n:m-Table for a Name->Attribute relationship

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have two tables, let's say "Names" and "Addresses". Now I want make a table that links idName to idAddress in a n:m relationship. For this table, there are multiple solutions:
1. Own Link-ID as Primary Key
2. Primary Key over the two id columns
3. Just an index over the two id columns (known as Heap-Table)
4. maybe even more?

Here is an SQLFiddle for my Example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/77665/7

Somehow I feel the artificial primary key is unneeded, on the other hand it's a good practice to have a single-column key for every table. So, the question is, what apprach would you reccomend and why? Or is there some other approach i'm missing?

Comment: The question is basically about DB design, but I'm open to performance remarks for SQLServer 2008 specifically

Comment: Yes, I'm counting on the fact that the unique constraints in the SQLFiddle create indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the unique IDENTITY column: this assures that the primary key of a new insert is always increasing. This is important as it means that inserts will always be at the end of the index and never somewhere in the middle of it. Inserting into the middle of an index can cause problems if the page it should go on is full: the page then has to be split into 2 (or more, depending on the actual index implementation). When that happens on an ordinary (non-clustered) index it's not generally a problem. When that happens to a clustered index, where the data is stored with the actual key, the problem is greater as it has to move around not just the keys but the data as well.

In most modern RDBM's such page-splitting isn't a problem. In older versions I did see one index split require the complete re-org of a large table of users in an e-commerce web site (using SQL Server 2000 I think) which had a GUID as a primary key. This meant that it had to take out a table lock and that basically stopped the site: no-one could use it as the user table was locked. It took several hours for us to sort it out and the site was offline rather longer than its owners wanted it to be...

Comment: I understand your point about insertion order. But the consequences of that are debated. There are lots of articles that suggest the use of a primary key that specifically randomizes insert positions to reduce congestion because always inserting at the end requires locking of the same page for all, possibly concurrent inserts.

Comment: True. But the cost of each lock on the last page is generally very low unless the transaction lasts a long time. The alternatives are to pay a very low price quite often, or a very large one rarely. The frequent low price events will probably not be noticed; the rare large price event will be.

Comment: I read up some more on the subject today and while I still have some more questions now, I agree with the "insert at the end is good" argument. Still, this means I have ANOTHER index (the unique), which suffers from exactly the same problems you describe, especially since it covers the entire table AGAIN. So now I have two indexes to modify...

Comment: The important thing is that it isn't the clustered index.